# Access violation RTTI dumping record containing record pointers

Tags: delphi, pointers, record, dump, rtti

```
uses RTTI;

type TMyRecord = packed record
  name : String[20];
  age  : Integer;
end;

type TMasterCtrl = packed record
  MyRecord: ^TMyRecord;  // Error can be avoided by changing to `MyRecord: Pointer;`
end;

procedure RTTIDump(Instance, ATypeInfo: Pointer; Memo: TStrings; NameWidth, FieldTypeWidth, ValueWidth: Integer; PaddingChar: Char);
var
  rType: TRTTIType;
  fields: TArray<TRttiField>;
  i: Integer;
begin
  rType := TRTTIContext.Create.GetType(ATypeInfo);
  Memo.Add(rType.ToString);
  fields := rType.GetFields;
  for i := 0 to High(fields) do
    Memo.Add(Format('%s: %s :: %s', [
      fields[i].Name.PadRight(NameWidth, PaddingChar),
      fields[i].FieldType.ToString.PadRight(FieldTypeWidth, PaddingChar),
      fields[i].GetValue(Instance).ToString.PadRight(FieldTypeWidth, PaddingChar) ]));
end;

procedure TForm3.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  myRecord    : TMyRecord;
  MasterCtrl: TMasterCtrl;
begin
myRecord.name := 'Fred Bloggs';
myRecord.age  := 23;

MasterCtrl.MyRecord := @myRecord;

RTTIDump(Addr(MasterCtrl), TypeInfo(TMasterCtrl), Memo1.Lines, 18, 18, 0, ' ');
end;
```

How to fix the access violation this code will create, still using pointer to record?

Comment: Please don't post random code without explaining what the actual problem is with it, which line of  code is failing, error messages, etc.

Comment: Ok.  Next time I will put comment at line 9 "Error can be avoided by changing to `MyRecord: Pointer;`" at end before the question "How to fix the access violation this code will create, still using pointer to record?"  Happy?

Comment: I don't understand why you use short strings, or why you pack your records

Comment: File I am reading is made that way...

Comment: You don't have to make your internal records identical

Comment: Will fix David.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As LU RD said, you have to declare a proper pointer type for `TMyRecord` to get the correct RTTI generated for the `TMasterCtrl.MyRecord` field, otherwise the `field[s].FieldType` property crashes because there is no type information to retreive.

```
type
  PMyRecord = ^TMyRecord; // <-- here
  TMyRecord = packed record
    name : String[20];
    age  : Integer;
  end;

  TMasterCtrl = packed record
    MyRecord: PMyRecord;  
  end;
```

That being said, there are two other problems with your code:

1. `fields[i].GetValue(@Instance)`

   `Instance` already contains the address of the `TMasterCtrl` instance.  By using `@`, you are passing the wrong address to `GetValue()`.  You need to drop the `@`:

   ```
    fields[i].GetValue(Instance)
   ```
2. do not call `rType.Free`.  `TRttiContext` owns it and will free it for you.

Comment: 3. Not checking to see if `fields[i].FieldType` is assigned before using it.

Comment: @NicholasRing: One would not typically expect `FieldType` to fail, though. This is a fluke in RTTI generation, not retrieval.

Comment: it is not a fluke but a bug in the RTTI generation, so testing to see if it is assigned or not is a precautionary measure.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a proper type declaration for your pointer.

```
type
  PMyRecord =^TMyRecord;
  TMyRecord = packed record
  name : String[20];
  age  : Integer;
end;

type TMasterCtrl = packed record
  MyRecord: PMyRecord;  
end;
```